# Searching a file inside a .tar.gz file by date in unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I would like to ask if there is a way to search for a file inside a .tar.gz file without extracting it? If there is, is there a way to search for that file by date?

My OS is AIX.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by search here?  Are you looking for a file with a particular name or do you want to search inside the contents of the files within the archive?

Comment: yes, I am looking for a particular filename inside the archived file

Comment: this one seem to work but how do I figure out when is the date it was created: $gunzip -c file.tar.gz | tar tvf - | grep filename

Answer (score 0):

`tar` can be instructed to preserve atimes on files it archives, but not all tars do this, and I am unfortunately not familiar with AIX-specific tar in this case. What you need to know is whether tar was invoked with `--atime-preserve` (AIX tar may not support this; be sure to check), and when you call an extraction you must use the `-p` flag. So, you'd have something like this:

```
tar zxpf file.tar.gz the/file/you/want.txt
```

You will likely find that Unix (cf Linux) tar won't support the `-j` and `-z` so you would have to use:

```
gzip -dc file.tar.gz | tar xf - the/file/you/want.txt
```

to run the command from a pipe. In this case, you would need to know the name of the file you want extracted, which you can get from:

```
tar tf file.tar.gz
```

using compression as required. Obviously you can tack on a `| grep foo` if you are looking for a file named foo.

It is not, I do not think, possible to extract a file from tar based upon the modification date of the file in the tarball – at least I was not able to find support for such in the documentation. Remember, `tar` is just the tape archiver and is not meant to do such fancy things. :-)

Lastly, you can do this:

```
tar xvf file.tar `tar tf file.tar | grep foo`
```

if you want to pull out all the files matching 'foo' from `file.tar` (compression above yada yada). I do not suggest running that command on an actual tape drive!

Answer (score 0):

$ tar tzf archive.tar.gz | grep "search"

Comment: Adding some context behind that command would be helpful in fleshing out your answer.